# Как скачать большой файл с google drive?

Tags: java, android, google-drive

Использую вот такой вот код чтобы скачать большой файл с google drive:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadZipSynch(String idFile) {
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            mDriveService.files().get(idFile)
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            return (ByteArrayOutputStream) outputStream;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Получаю исключение:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 551813136 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 243MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 306688176, growth limit 536870912
```

Исключение видимо намекает что я должен грузить файл по частям. Хорошо как это сделать? Я нашел вот ссылку https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download там используется такой код:

```
class CustomProgressListener implements MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener {
  public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) {
    switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
      case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
        System.out.println(downloader.getProgress());
        break;
      case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
        System.out.println("Download is complete!");
    }
  }
}

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/driveFile.jpg");

DriveFiles.Get request = drive.files().get(fileId);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

Возможно он подойдет? Только вот у меня класса DriveFiles нету может это какая то другая библиотека я не пойму вообще в build.gradle я имплементировал это:
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20220815-2.0.0'
И в libs проекта кинул файл `google-api-client-android-2.0.0.jar`

Comment: 1.  если файл большой то лучше бы его порезать предварительно на "кусочки и качать в несколько потоков".  2. Файл большой  и не помещается в  heap, то  придется резать однозначно. 3.  Попробуйте использовать ByteBuffer

Comment: DownloadManager чем плох?

Comment: задача стоит-  написать программу самому

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю про ByteBuffer. Ну у меня вот после этого исключение выскакивает mDriveService.files().get(idFile) .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream); Да они пишут да надо по частям если большой файл, но как толком нигде не написано.

Comment: Ну там мне надо скачать один zip файл неизвестного размера, но скорее всего большого. А как это сделать хз.

Comment: Если хотите сами, то используйте классический Java подход через FileOutputStream и качаете через буфер скорее всего в сервисе.

Comment: Вы скачиваете файл в `ByteArrayOutputStream`, то есть в хип - естественно он не помещается, но дальше вы же что-то с ним делаете, наверняка в файл записываете - так и пишите сразу в файловый поток вместо `ByteArrayOutputStream`